# Using pointers to reverse a String

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings

Trying to reverse a String in C using pointers and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
int main(void) 
{
    char sentence[100];
    printf("Enter any string: ");

    scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);

    char *sPtr;
    sPtr = sentence;
    int length = 0;

    printf("Original string = %s\n", sentence);

    while (*sPtr != '\0') {
        ++length;
        ++sPtr;
    }

    printf("Reverse string = ");

    for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%c", *(sPtr + 1));
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (sPtr+1) ??  
(sPtr+i)

Comment: The `sPtr` points to the terminating null character after exiting the `while` loop. Then the `for` loop to print the character array in reverse order should be, for instance, `for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) putchar(*(sPtr - i));`

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
while (*sPtr != '\0') {
    ++length;
    ++sPtr;
}
```

At this point the sPtr point at the end of the string so in the second loop it never decrement.

```
for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr+1));
}
```

**A possible solution can be this:**

```
for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr));
    --sPtr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me find the solution, the only thing missing was in the printf() inside the for loop. Where it should be *(sPtr + length)

Comment: No because you increment it before

Comment: @zigrazor Perhaps you should decrement the pointer first then print it as pointer is already pointing to \0 char.

Comment: I tried using the code you provided but the nothing was being printed in the output

Comment: Oh yes, you will see the /0 char, but it works everywhere

Comment: @Jordan there is something you miss... retry

Answer (score 1):

You are always print a character past the end of the string.

```
for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr+1));
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr-(length-i));
}
```

or

```
   for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
        sPtr--; //decrement first as sPtr will be pointing to \0 char
        printf("%c", *sPtr);
    }
```

Comment: 'for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr-length-i));
}'     This is incorrect because you have to add i if you subtract lenght

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with. Thanks for the help anyone provided!

```
while (*sPtr != '\0') {
    ++length;
    ++sPtr;
}

printf("Reverse string = ");

sPtr = sentence;

for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr+length));
    --sPtr;
}
```

Comment: Again it is an incorrect code.  The expression *(sPtr+length)) is not being changed in the loop. And you are using integer variables along with pointers. And the code does not reverse a string. One more see my answer. It is the only answer that provides the correct solution that satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write separate functions for such a tasks.
2. When you test the function try to reduce number of unknown factors. In your case do not `scanf` just use known strings. scanf may fail and you will not know if it your function, or the user input.

Simple function, no library functions used.

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *head = str, *tail = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*tail) tail++;
        tail--;
        while(tail > head)   
        {
            int ch = *tail;
            *tail-- = *head;
            *head++ = ch;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EgNLpF

Answer (score -1):

After this loop

```
while (*sPtr != '\0') {
    ++length;
    ++sPtr;
}
```

the pointer sPtr points to the terminating zero. So in the next loop you are starting to output the string from the indeterminate character after the terminating zero.

```
for (int i = length; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", *(sPtr+1));
}
```

The expression `*(sPtr+1)` is not being changed in the loop.

Take into account that you are not reversing a string. You are trying to output a string in the reverse order. It is not the same. Also you are using an intermediate variable of the type int.

To reverse a string using only pointers the code can look the following way.

```
char *last = sentence;

while ( *last ) ++last;

if ( sentence != last )
{
    for ( char *first = sentence; first < --last; ++first )
    {
        char c = *first;
        *first = *last;
        *last = c;
    }
}

printf( "Reversed string = %s\n", sentence );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char sentence[100] = { '\0' };

    printf( "Enter any string: " );
    scanf("%99[^\n]s", sentence );

    char *last = sentence;

    while ( *last ) ++ last;

    if ( sentence != last )
    {
        for ( char *first = sentence; first < --last; ++first )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = c;
        }
    }

    printf( "Reversed string = %s\n", sentence );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter any string: Hello Jordan
Reversed string = nadroJ olleH
```

You could write a separate function that reverse a string. Just move the code that reverses a string from main into a separate function like

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    char *last = s;

    while ( *last ) ++last;

    if ( s != last )
    {
        for ( char *first = s; first < --last; ++first )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char sentence[100] = { '\0' };

    printf( "Enter any string: " );
    scanf("%99[^\n]s", sentence );

    printf( "Revresed string = %s\n", reverse( sentence ) );

    return 0;
}
```

If you want just to output a string in the reverse order using pointers then the program can be very simple.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char sentence[100] = { '\0' };

    printf( "Enter any string: " );
    scanf("%99[^\n]s", sentence );

    const char *sPtr = sentence;

    while ( *sPtr ) ++ sPtr;

    printf( "Revresed string = ");

    while ( sPtr != sentence ) putchar( *--sPtr );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Even more simply implementation you could make by means of a recursive function. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reversed_output( const char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        reversed_output( s + 1 );
        putchar( *s );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char sentence[100] = { '\0' };

    printf( "Enter any string: " );
    scanf("%99[^\n]s", sentence );

    printf( "Revresed string = ");

    reversed_output( sentence );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So after the while loop I set sPtr = sentence; but now in the output I am only getting a series of 'o's... strange

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually got it working by decrementing the sPtr in the for loop and using printf("%c", *(sPtr + length))

Comment: @Jordan In any case this approach does not satisfies the assignment. You shall not use an intermediate variable like length and you are not reversing a string. Reread my answer anew.